# Merach MR 667 Exercise Bike Quic Sound?

Tags: noise, indoor, stationary-bike

I have Merach MR 667 Exercise Bike.

It worked very well for year, suddenly it started making a sound in a pedal.

Sound seems like some friction between metal or quic sound.

Has anyone have any Idea how to fix?

Comment: You are talking about [this](https://merachfitness.com/products/exercise-bike-silver-mr-636) trainer? Looking at images of it, have you checked that all exposed bolts are tight? Can you shoot a video of the problem and edit/link it into your question? You said you have it for a year, so it is still under warranty? So, I wouldn't take it further apart than maybe removing the pedals (if possible) and contact the manufacturer - I tried to find (service) manuals on their page but all the downloads seem to be broken.

Comment: OK, it is actually [this](https://merachfitness.com/products/mr-667-spin-bike) one but that doesn't change much from my first reply: I would massively help if you could somehow locate the issue. If it isn't something trivial and obvious as a bolt requiring tightening, I think you should describe/document the issue as good as possible and get in touch with the manufacturer's support. We here definitely need more input ...

Comment: What is "quic" ?